# Do you report F values for a mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model

I am new to mixed-models. I am using a mixed effects model to account for the fact that each of my participants were measured at 12 different sites on their back muscles and I want to see how contractile properties vary at each vertebral level and left vs right sude of the back.

My quesrion is regarding the write up for a journal paper. What values do I need to report? Do i need to report F values or is that just for ANOVAs?

Thanks

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#tests-of-effects-i.e.testing-that-several-parameters-are-simultaneously-zero